# Attempting If Elif Else Statement, only get two values returned

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to write an If Elif Else statement, and I may be approaching this incorrectly. I've built a DataFrame with Pandas, and what I'm attempting to do is signify 1 of 3 statuses in the column. Special Order, Ready to Ship, and just blank or a hyphen. I've tried this several different ways but can't seem to get it to function. What I'm attempting to do is if something has a price of $0.00 to return that third status of just blank or hyphen. Currently regardless of what I do I get either Special Order or Ready to Ship.

This is the code from the website, I apologize it's so messy it's just the way it was formatted from them.

```
   <table cellspacing="0" class="item width-100" summary="Wish list">
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="wish_products" value="583454" class="wish_check  available " /></td>
              <td class="image">
                <a title="A Walk Through Hell Complete Hc" href="/a-walk-through-hell-complete-hc.html">
                                      <img src="https://www.cheapgraphicnovels.com/images/P/A%20WALK%20THROUGH%20HELL%20COMPLETE%20HC.jpg" width="97" alt="A WALK THROUGH HELL COMPLETE HC" title="A WALK THROUGH HELL COMPLETE HC" />                                  </a>
              </td>
              <td class="details">

                                <a title="A Walk Through Hell Complete Hc" href="/a-walk-through-hell-complete-hc.html" class="product-title">A WALK THROUGH HELL COMPLETE HC</a>

                <div class="descr"><p>
    <span style="font-size:14px;">Garth Ennis&#39; Complete Masterpiece of Terror in One Unrelenting Hardcover! So these two FBI agents walk into a warehouse... Special Agents Shaw and McGregor handle the routine cases nowadays, which is just the way Shaw likes it.</span></p>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<p>
    <strong><span style="font-size:14px;">ESTIMATED ARRIVAL: TBA</span></strong></p>
</div>
        
                                  <span class="product-price-text">
                    <span class="currency">$29.99</span> x <input type="text" size="3" name="quantity" id="qty_583454" value="1" /> = 
                  </span>
                  <span class="price">
                    <span class="currency">$29.99</span>
                  </span>
                  <span class="market-price">
                    
                  </span>
 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="buttons-row">

    <a class="simple-button simple-delete-button" href="cart.php?mode=wldelete&amp;wlitem=583454&amp;eventid=" title="Delete item"><span>Delete item</span></a>
    
              </td>
              <td class="buttons-row">

  <button class="button light-button" type="submit" title="Update">
  <span class="button-right"><span class="button-left">Update</span></span>
  </button>

                  <div class="button-separator"></div>
                            
<div style="float:left"> 
        <a href="javascript://" onclick="javascript: self.location = 'cart.php?mode=wl2cart&amp;wlitem=583454&amp;amount='+$('#qty_583454').val()"><img src="/skin/common_files/images/add_cart_btn_hov.png" border="0" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
                                     
              </td>
            </tr>

                                     <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">                 
<div class="ordernow">This title is available by Special Order only.  Please read our <a href="/covid-19.html">COVID-19 Update</a> prior to ordering.</div>
                </td>
              </tr>

                          <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                                  </td>
              </tr>
            
          </table>
          
          <table cellspacing="0" class="item width-100" summary="Wish list">
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="wish_products" value="584040" class="wish_check " /></td>
              <td class="image">
                <a title="Abe Sapien Dark And Terrible Vol 01 Hc" href="/abe-sapien-dark-and-terrible-vol-01-hc.html">
                                      <img src="https://www.cheapgraphicnovels.com/images/P/ABE%20SAPIEN%20DARK%20%26%20TERRIBLE%20HC%20VOL%2001.jpg" width="98" alt="ABE SAPIEN DARK AND TERRIBLE VOL 01 HC " title="ABE SAPIEN DARK AND TERRIBLE VOL 01 HC " />                                  </a>
              </td>
              <td class="details">

                                <a title="Abe Sapien Dark And Terrible Vol 01 Hc" href="/abe-sapien-dark-and-terrible-vol-01-hc.html" class="product-title">ABE SAPIEN DARK AND TERRIBLE VOL 01 HC </a>

                <div class="descr"><p>
    <span style="font-size:14px;">On the run from the BPRD, a newly mutated Abe Sapien-more inhuman than before-travels across a United States transformed and overrun by monsters. Abe&#39;s search for the truth about himself-or his race away from his fate-mirrors the quest of an ancient necromancer to seize control of a world literally going to hell. </span></p>
</div>
       
                                  <span class="product-price-text">
                    <span class="currency">$24.49</span> x <input type="text" size="3" name="quantity" id="qty_584040" value="0" /> = 
                  </span>
                  <span class="price">
                    <span class="currency">$0.00</span>
                  </span>
                  <span class="market-price">
                    
                  </span>
                
                                  <strong>Out of stock</strong>
                
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="buttons-row">

    <a class="simple-button simple-delete-button" href="cart.php?mode=wldelete&amp;wlitem=584040&amp;eventid=" title="Delete item"><span>Delete item</span></a>
   
              </td>
              <td class="buttons-row">

  <button class="button light-button" type="submit" title="Update">
  <span class="button-right"><span class="button-left">Update</span></span>
  </button>

                  <div class="button-separator"></div>
                
                
              </td>
            </tr>
    
                          <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                                  </td>
              </tr>
            
          </table>
```

This is my code so far, it functions, I just can't get the If, Elif, Else part to work under special order.

```
titles = []
links = []
price = []
special_order = []
addtocart = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
cgn_items = soup.find_all('table', class_='item width-100')
sleep(randint(2,10))

for container in cgn_items:

    #name
    name = container.find('a', class_='product-title').text.strip()
    titles.append(name)
    
    #link
    link = container.find('td', attrs={'class' : 'details'})
    for div in link:
        linking = container.find('a')['href']
        link = "https://www.cheapgraphicnovels.com" + linking
    links.append(link)
    
    #price
    pricing = container.find('span', class_='price')
    if pricing:
        price.append(pricing.text.strip())
    else:
        price.append('-')
    
    #special order
    special = container.find('div', class_='ordernow')
    if special:
        special_order.append('Special Order')
    else:
        special_order.append('Ready to Ship')
    
    #addtocart
    cart = container.find('img', {"src" : "/skin/common_files/images/add_cart_btn_hov.png"})
    if cart:
        addtocart.append('In Stock')
    else:
        addtocart.append('Out of Stock')

cgn_wishlist = pd.DataFrame({
'book': titles,
'link': links,
'price': price,
'special_order': special_order,
'cart': addtocart
})

cgn_wishlist.to_csv('cgn_wishlist.csv', index=False)
```

Currently it functions if it finds the ordernow class it knows to assign Special Order, for everything else it just gets Ready to Ship. But what I would like is for anything that has a price of $0.00 to be blank or "-", and the remainder items (which would be considered in stock as they have a price above $0.00) would get "Ready to Ship"

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: check the content of `special ` and you will know the issue.

Comment: Your link code also need fixing. It appears to be looking for multiple links but only uses `find` not `find_all`. It then overwrites the `link` variable. `links.append(link)` is also outside the loop?

Comment: @MartinEvans Thanks, it does appear to functioning as it should as I find all instances of item width-100 then with in that I'm looking for td.details, and within that there is only the one link? I gets the data I need but if it's still wrong and can be improved, I'm all ears as I'm still super new to this and want to make sure things are done right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you just need to add an additional `elif` in your "special order" code as follows:

```
#special order
special = container.find('div', class_='ordernow')
if special:
    special_order.append('Special Order')
elif price[-1] in ['-', '$0.00']:
    special_order.append('-')
else:
    special_order.append('Ready to Ship')
```

This checks if the price is either `-` or `$0.00` and then adds `-` instead.

This should give you dataframe such as:

```
                    book                   link   price  special_order          cart
0  A WALK THROUGH HEL...  https://www.cheapg...  $29.99  Special Order      In Stock
1  ABE SAPIEN DARK AN...  https://www.cheapg...   $0.00              -  Out of Stock
```

`price` is your list of prices, the last entry in the list is `price[-1]`, negative values start from the end of the list (`price[0]` would be the first value). Python's `in` operator checks to see if a value matches any value from a list. As you have two tests, these can be made into a list of values to test for e.g. `['-', '$0.00']`

Comment: Thanks for the help on this @Martin Evans, worked a treat! The issue I was running into is anyway I wrote the elif portion of the statement would not work which is why I only had if and else statements when I posted the code.

Comment: As a follow up @MartinEvans could you explain to me the price[-1] in ['-', '$0.00'] ? Thanks!